# Scrape LIKE user of competition pages

Tags: facebook, like, page

Is it possible to make something a little touchy.. I will explain

My friend have a little baby accessory like hair clip and so.... She manage to get 100 like in there Facebook page (great!) NOW, on Facebook, in the same city, in the same market, a person with the same shop have 475 like in the Facebook page :-(

AND THE QUESTION, the competition in closing there shop soon.... So is it possible to get the name of ALL THE like in the competition page and send a personal message to ALL of them to tell the we still offer the same product, and ask people to switch and like there page.... It’s like stealing the consumer database of the competition.... But seem a good idea to me...

NOW, is it possible to make it automatic scraping user ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only scrape the peoples names who have liked the competitions page, however you would need to have access-rights to view those names, and if you don't then the answer is NO.

Now, may I suggest you try a different tactic, because you may find that this backfires if you approach all of those people, some people might not appreciate that sort of tactic.

I would try different techniques to generate more likes, do more in your existing FB community to try and promote others to share your website amongst their friends, this way they are doing it because they *want* to, plus your site is more likely to go viral in this manner.  You are going to have to get creative, scraping people of a like-list is a little desperate to be honest, genuine interest is much likely to go viral.

EDIT: Just to add, have you tried contacting the competition who are closing down to perhaps network with them to generate interest in your site...?  You never know.

Comment: Just to add a TINY bit more that I think you were hinting at Mantorok. If you network with the competition who's closing down soon, then you can ask THEM for all of the names instead of creating something complicated and most likely against the Terms of Use for Facebook that could lead to your Fanpage getting taken off entirely.

Comment: Yep - that was what I was hinting at :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make a Facebook Ad and target it only at people that have liked your competitors fanpage. This will cost you a few dollars, but since we are talking about a very small number of people, it shouldn't be much. The people that are really interested will like your friend's page, but keep in mind many might not. A few hundred likes for a business is very very little and it is highly possible that most of those likes are personal friends of the business owner and this is why they have liked the page, not because they are actually interested in hair accessories. This might also be the reason they are closing shop.